# Plotting data using Flot and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flot

So I am trying to create a realtime plot of data that is being recorded to a SQL server.  The format is as follows:

Database: testDB
Table: sensors
First record contains 3 records.  The first column is an auto incremented ID starting at 1.  The second column is the time in epoch format.  The third column is my sensor data.  It is in the following format:

23432.32 112343.3 53454.322 34563.32 76653.44 000.000 333.2123

I am completely lost on how to complete this project.  I have read many pages showing examples dont really understand them.  They provide source code, but I am not sure where that code goes.  I installed httpd on my server and that is where I stand.  Does anyone know of a good how-to from beginning to end that I could follow?  Or could someone post a good step by step for me to follow?

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you want this displayed as a webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a httpd server
2. Install php
3. Write a php script to fetch the data from the database and render it
   as a webpage.

This is fairly elaborate request, with relatively little details given.  More information will allow us to give better answers.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I have installed HTTPD server, and I have installed php.  Both using YUM.  I tested PHP by using the following code:  <?php Print "Hello, World!"; ?>  and that works fine.  So I found the following example:  http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/gd-linegp.php  I created db.php also based on a previous tutorial on their site.  When run, I get a blank web page.  I posted my "echo" statement ABOVE the import db.php line, and it is displayed.  I put the "echo" statement BELOW import db.php, and it will NOT display on the web page.  Could I be missing some type of config?

Comment: Looks like I had to uninstall php-mysql then re-install it using yum.  Restarted httpd service and now I am able to query the db.  So, does anyone know of a step by step example to pull data from my sql server and plot it using FLOT?